# Set dynamic button layout as XML file without id?

Tags: android

So I created XML layout for buttons only.

buttons.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/b1" >
</Button>
```

main.java

```
public void addButton() {
    Button btn=new Button(this);
}
```

so how to set buttons.xml layout to btn without using id ?

Comment: when I used 
Button btn = (Button) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.buttons, null);
so it dosent math height and width in xml file !

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:utilidades="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.movidromo.ifilmfest"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/buttonContainer">
</LinearLayout >
```

And in your code, you can add to this linear layout your buttons with its properties:

```
Button yourNewButton = new Button (getBaseContext());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lparams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
yourNewButton.setLayoutParams(lparams);
yourNewButton.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
yourNewButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
yourNewButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourBackground);
LinearLayout layButtons = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.buttonContainer);
layButtons.addView(yourNewButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically you can set `Height` `Width` etc.

Layout `custom_button.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true">
</Button>
```

In code

```
private void createView() {
    btn = (Button)(context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_button, null));
    btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, iconId, 0, 0);
    btn.setText(btnText);
    btn.setTextColor(btnTextColor);
    btn.setTextSize(btnTextSize);
    btn.setBackgroundDrawable(btnBackGrad);
    btn.setMinimumHeight(50);
    btn.setWidth(50);
    btn.setPadding(0, 5, 0, 0);
}
```

I hope this can help you out.